# What varieties of beans are high in calories?

Tags: nutrient-composition, beans, calories

Which beans have the most calories per dry-weight?

Note: This includes anything someone might refer to as a "bean" and excludes foods that are perishable.

Comment: I don't think we can really comment on varieties being "hard to digest", as that can mean very different things depending on who is eating them. Anyway, that's essentially a health question, so I've edited this to stick to the food/cooking aspect.

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly pointless to answer, the general calorie difference between bean varieties is less than the difference from sub-varieties and growing conditions

Use wikipedia or wolframalpha to get average figures for the beans you can get locally, but you really need to test them if this is truly important

For what it's worth chickpeas are very high and commonly available. Wheat is much higher still!

- Beans are around 1 to 1.5 calories per g
- Wheat is around 3 calories per g
- Chia seed is around 5 calories per g
- Dried beef is also around 5 calories per g, and much tastier :-)

Comment: I think taste is a subjective matter, as you couldn't pay me to eat beef, but I'll happily gobble up some delicious beans.